# Perl - Why am I getting "ERROR: Incorrect argument in parentheses"?

Tags: perl, variables, arguments, package

Basically, I'm trying to call a package function using only variables/scalars but I can't figure out why I'm getting "ERROR: Incorrect argument in parentheses".

Here's the sample pm:

```
package foo;

sub bar {

    my $request = @_[0];

    if ($request eq 'fubar') {

        my $response = 'definitely';
        return $response;

    else {

        my $response = 'definitely not';
        return $response;

    }

}

1;
```

And the sample pl

```
use strict;
use lib "/blah/blah/custom_modules";
use sample;

my $package = 'foo';
my $package_sub = 'bar';
my $package_sub_args = 'fubar';     
my $response = $package->$package_sub("$package_args");
print "$response\n";
```

And then I get the error.

Using any variations of the following will work however:

```
my $response = foo::bar('fubar');
my $response = foo::bar($package_sub_args);
```

But I believe that I cannot use variables in the type of OO notation above and must use the -> notation.

Anyway, help very much appreciated.

CLARIFICATION - The issue I'm having is with not knowing the package, sub or arguments until runtime. I can make it work when the sub doesn't require arguments. But I have several subs that do require arguments and that's where I'm stumbling...

Comment: I believe one way to call a sub indirectly is with &{$mysub}($param); and either a string that names the sub $mysub = "foo::bar" or a reference $mysub = \&foo::bar ;

Comment: Do you not know the package or subroutine names until runtime?

Comment: @JonahBishop - Yes, I don't know the package name, the sub or the arguments until runtime

Comment: @Paul -arggh sorry dude - you had it first. I'll get you next time

Comment: I guess, you have a curly brace missing in `if` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simpler:

```
my $package_sub_ref = \&{ $package . '::' . $package_sub };
my $response = $package_sub_ref->($package_sub_arg);
```

Works with strict.

Comment: Then you changed something. Try again. (The only think I changed is that I removed the 's' from misnamed `$package_sub_args`.) Be sure to use `use strict; use warnings;`. You probably made a typo.

Comment: You're right. I had an extra set of double colons so this works - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're doing this because you don't know either the package name or subroutine name until runtime. An older edition of the Perl Cookbook has this recipe using symbolic references in it:

```
{
    no strict 'refs';
    $val  = ${ $packname . "::" . $varname }; # Scalar
    @vals = @{ $packname . "::" . $aryname }; # Array
    &{ $packname . "::" . $funcname }("args"); # Function Call 1
    ($packname . "::" . $funcname) -> ("args"); # Function Call 2
}
```

In this example, the `no strict 'refs'` line is used to thwart the symbolic reference limitations that `use strict;` imposes (assuming you're using that ... and you should be). Then, examples for accessing a scalar, array, and two subroutines are shown.